# Smart way to enlarge image on hover

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to mimic [this](http://www.dreamstime.com/stock-photography-should-catapult-my-career-vikings-image29383102) on have image event? 
On hover image enlarges but it is done in smart way - it knows were browser window ends and all the times it manages to reposition enlarged image so it always shows full image.

Foto example of what I am talking about: 
[image: example1]
[image: example2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First assign a mouseover and mouseout event handler to the image class that sets a flag variable to true and false. On the mouseover event, get the img source then display that image in the viewing box. If the flag variable is true, then display the viewing box and adjust it's position according to the mouse's position. As far as deciding which side of the mouse to display the image on, I would recommend simply checking if the mouse is farther than half way across the x axis. You can do this by checking if `event.clientX > window.innerWidth/2`